# Why do my one to many relationships in subclasses get a cycle error?

Tags: entity-framework, .net-core, one-to-many, parent

I want to have a one-to-many relation between subclasses of one master class,
and in second step use of master class for relationships with other class
please see below models:

**BasePost.cs**

```
public abstract class BasePost
{   
    [Key]
    public long Id { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Comment> Comments { get; set; }

}
```

**Question.cs:**

```
 public class Question: BasePost
{
    
    [Required] public string Title { get; set; }

    public string Body { get; set; }
    
    public ICollection<Answer> Answers { get; set; }
}
```

**Answer.cs**

```
 public class Answer: BasePost
{
    public string Body { get; set; }

    public int Vote { get; set; }
    public Question Question { get; set; }
    public long QuestionId { get; set; }
}
```

**Comment.cs**

```
public class Comment
{
    [Key]
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public BasePost BasePost { get; set; }
    public long BasePostId { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }
}
```

**and finally in ApplicationDbContext.cs :**

```
        builder.Entity<Answer>()
            .HasOne(x => x.Question)
            .WithMany(a => a.Answers)
            .HasForeignKey(k => k.QuestionId)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);

builder.Entity<Comment>()
            .HasOne(x => x.BasePost)
            .WithMany(a => a.Comments)
            .HasForeignKey(k => k.BasePostId)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull);
```

but after migration and update database I get below error:

> Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_BasePosts_BasePosts_QuestionId' on table 'BasePosts' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.

Comment: Where's `QuestionId`?

Comment: I think when object inherit from BasePost dose not need to define Id again. this is wrong?

Comment: `public Question Question { get; set; }` is a self-reference in the SQL table. That's always a reference cycle.

Comment: I guess you realize that this entity model is mapped to a single database table due to [TPH](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relational/inheritance#conventions) inheritance strategy, so all the relationships between derived entities are self table references as @Gert mentioned and cause multiple cascade paths.